# C++: How to replace a complex iteration with a single command?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration

**Question**

I sometimes have complicated iteration process that must be repeated several times in the code but the expression that is being performed at each iteration differ at different places of the code. Having to rewrite the iteration process everywhere is ugly and is error prone. How can I just wrap this iteration process?

**Example**

Consider for example this relatively complex iteration

```
std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

// print integers and permute bitmask
do {
    // Loop through BIG and SMALL indices
    for (size_t BIGindex = 0; BIGindex < nbBigs; ++BIGindex)
    {
        size_t nbSmalls;
        if (BIGindex == nbBigs)
        {
            nbSmalls = nbSmallsOfLastBig;
        } else
        {
            nbSmalls = nbSmallsStandard;
        }
        for (size_t SMALLindex = 0; SMALLindex < nbSmalls; ++SMALLindex)
        {
            // doStuff with bitmask, BIGindex and SMALLindex
        }        
    }
} while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
```

How can I define a command / alias (for lack of a better word) such as 'doComplexIteration' that would wrap all these iterations into a simpler command. Something like

```
doComplexIteration
{
    // doStuff with bitmask, BIGindex and SMALLindex       
}
```

**One not fully satisfying solution**

One way to do that would be to wrap the stuff to be done in a function such as

```
void doComplexIterationOnFunction(void (*doStuff)(std::string bitmask, size_t BIGindex, size_t SMALLindex))
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        // Loop through BIG and SMALL indices
        for (size_t BIGindex = 0; BIGindex < nbBigs; ++BIGindex)
        {
            size_t nbSmalls;
            if (BIGindex == nbBigs)
            {
                nbSmalls = nbSmallsOfLastBig;
            } else
            {
                nbSmalls = nbSmallsStandard;
            }
            for (size_t SMALLindex = 0; SMALLindex < nbSmalls; ++SMALLindex)
            {
                (*doStuff)(bitmask, BIGindex, SMALLindex);
            }        
        }
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
}
```

and then call it as

```
doComplexIterationOnFunction(doSpecificStuff);
```

however, it forces me to systematically wrap any code that I would like to be performed at each iteration in a function which is a little cumbersome and a little silly as sometimes the code is very short.

Comment: You can pass a lambda if you don't want to define a function.

Comment: A lambda is the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of taking a function pointer you can just make the function a template type and then that allows you to pass a lambda at the call site.  That would look like

```
temaplte<typename Function>
void doComplexIterationOnFunction(Function doStuff)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        // Loop through BIG and SMALL indices
        for (size_t BIGindex = 0; BIGindex < nbBigs; ++BIGindex)
        {
            size_t nbSmalls;
            if (BIGindex == nbBigs)
            {
                nbSmalls = nbSmallsOfLastBig;
            } else
            {
                nbSmalls = nbSmallsStandard;
            }
            for (size_t SMALLindex = 0; SMALLindex < nbSmalls; ++SMALLindex)
            {
                std::invoke(doStuff, bitmask, BIGindex, SMALLindex);
            }        
        }
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
}
```

Then you would call it like

```
doComplexIterationOnFunction(doSpecificStuffFunction) // pass function
doComplexIterationOnFunction(doSpecificStuffFuntor) // pass functor
doComplexIterationOnFunction([](auto foo, auto bar, auto baz) { return foo + bar - baz; }) // pass lambda
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a different option:

Invert control, by writing a range, or at least enough of one to [use range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
struct ComplexIterationRange {
    static constexpr auto end() noexcept { struct {} r; return r; }
    static auto begin() {
        struct {
            std::string bitmask;
            std::size_t SMALLindex = 0, BIGindex = 0;
            const auto& operator*() const noexcept { return *this; }
            auto& operator++() noexcept {
                if (++SMALLindex >= nbSmallsStandard) {
                    if (++BIGindex >= nbBigs) {
                        if (!std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()))
                            return *this;
                        BIGindex = 0;
                    }
                    SMALLindex = 0;
                }
                return *this;
            }
            bool operator!=(decltype(end())) const noexcept {
                return SMALLindex < nbSmallsStandard || BIGindex < nbBigs;
            }
        } r { []{ std::string r(K, 1); r.resize(N, 0); return r; }() };
        return r;
    }
};
```

Use it like:

```
for (auto&& x : ComplexIterationRange()) {
    Use x.SMALLindex, x.BIGindex, and x.bitmask here
    ...
}
```

The advantage over passing a function-pointer, or even lambda to a template-function is greater flexibility and control for the caller.
The cost is tying your brain into knots while writing the range.